# Why Do Graphics Get Smaller Using Affine Transform in Java

Tags: java, affinetransform

I'm pretty new to Affine Transformations and am finding a few things quite frustrating..

I've been working on a personal project that draws a laser (think Star Wars) on the screen.  I use the RadialGradientPaint class to draw the glow for the laser, and then use scale and rotate Affine Transformations to change the oval's shape and turn the laser in a specific direction.

When I try to rotate the graphic (without the scale), it appears to shrink it, and I'm not sure why this is.  I've tried looking this up to no avail.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the Java Doc on this class.  Why is this?

I'm also curious as to how I can get the transformed object to move to the same location as an un-transformed graphic.  Both graphics move to different places even with the same coordinates.  I know this might be due to an Affine Transformation shifting the whole graph, and that I might have to translate the transformed graphic to get it to the same exact place as the un-transformed graphic, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here is the portion of my code that draws the laser:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {

        // If the graphic is visible on the frame, draw it
        if(onScreen()) {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Preserves the original presets of the program's graphics
            AffineTransform ogTransform = g2d.getTransform();
            Shape ogClip = g2d.getClip();

            Point2D center = new Point2D.Float(x, y);
            float[] dist = {0.3f, 0.9f};
            Color[] colors = {new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.9f), new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f)};
            g2d.setPaint(new RadialGradientPaint(center, radius, dist, colors));

            AffineTransform scaleTransform = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scaleX, scaleY);
            AffineTransform rotationTransform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle, x + width/2f, y + height/2f);

            // Transforms the shape to look more like a laser
            rotationTransform.concatenate(scaleTransform);
            g2d.setTransform(rotationTransform);

            // Draws a "cut-out" of the rectangle
            g2d.setClip(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2));
            g2d.fillRect(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

            // Default transformation and clip are set
            g2d.setTransform(ogTransform);
            g2d.setClip(ogClip);

            // Outlines where the transformed graphic should be
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.drawRect(x - 10, y - 10, 20, 20);

        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!